# Spring repository Hibernate build entity list based on associated entity list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository

I'm using Spring boot 1.5 and Hibernate. I have 2 entities, Person and PersonDetail which doesn't always exist. I need to retrieve a list of PersonDetails based on a Person list, even if matched PersonDetails doesn't exists.

So I wrote buildFromPersonList in PersonService which is working well. However I have filled my DB with 1000 entries of Person and unfortunately it takes about 3,5 seconds to build the list of PersonDetails.

Due to performances issues i'm trying to do it in JPQL please take a look at findAllByPersons and help me to improve it to get PersonDetails from PersonList and retrieve matching PersonDetails when it exists .

Here's my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    //name,birthdate ...

}
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_details")
public class PersonDetails{
// private details accessible only for authorized user
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_person",insertable = true,updatable=true,nullable = false)
    protected Person person;

}
```

Repository

```
@Transactional
public interface PersonDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonDetails,Long> {
    PersonDetails findByPerson(Person person);
    // @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN (pd is not null ) THEN pd ELSE (new PersonDetails(p)) END  FROM Person p left join PersonDetails pd on p.id=pd.person.id")
    @Query("SELECT new PersonDetails(p) FROM Person p")
    List<PersonDetails> findAllByPersons();

}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class PersonDetailsService {

    private final PersonDetailsRepository personDetailsRepository;
    private final PersonService personService;
    // constructors + findall, findOne,save

    @Override
    public List<PersonDetails> findAll() {
        List<Person> personList=personService.findAll();
        return buildFromList(personList);
     //   return personDetailsRepository.findAllByPerson();
    }

    private List<PersonDetails> buildFromPersonList( List<Person> personList) {

        List<PersonDetails> personDetailsList= new ArrayList<>();

        for (Person person:personList) {
            PersonDetails personDetails = personDetailsRepository.findByPersonperson);
            if(personDetails==null){
                personDetails=new PersonDetails();
                personDetails.setPerson(person);
            }
            personDetailsList.add(personDetail);

        }
        return personDetailsList;
    }
}
```

Update : I've implemented a new solution based on TheBakker idea but it still take too much time to load (between 800ms and 1s for only 1000 entries).
Does anyone have an idea to retrieve faster ?
Here's my new code :

```
@Transactional
public interface PersonDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonDetails,Long> {
    //..
    @Query("SELECT new PersonDetails(p) FROM Person p WHERE p.id not in (SELECT pd.person.id From PersonDetails pd)")
List<PersonDetails> findAllPersonNotInPersonDetails();

}
 @Service
public class PersonDetailsService {

    @Override
    public List<PersonDetails> findAll() {
       List<PersonDetails> personDetailsList=personDetailsRepository.findAll();

   /*       personDetailsList.addAll(personDetailsRepository.findAllPersonsNotInPersonDetails());

    return personDetailsList;*/

return Stream.concat(personDetailsList.stream(), agentDetailsRepository.findAllPersonNotInPersonDetails().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is, you are doing 1000 select queryies in your DB to get the personDetail for each individual Person.

Something that would be faster (but still perfectible) would be to do 2 queries :

1. One that get all the PersonDetails already in your DB
2. Another that would get all the person from your list that do not have a PersonDetails and for which you will need to loop on and instantiate one.

That way you change 1000 queries / transactions in 2, and you should definitly gain some.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I've implemented it but it still taking too long time to run. I've updated my post.